# Scala LinkedHashMap.toMap preserves order?

Tags: scala

As the title states, does converting a LinkedHashMap to a Map preserve the order in which elements are stored?

I believe not, but couldn't find any evidence.

Alternatively, is there any implementation of an immutable Map in Scala that preserves the order in which elements are inserted?

Answer (score 10):

The generic `Map` interface makes no such guarantee of ordering. Nor can it, as this would then rule out `HashMap` as a possible implementation.

I believe `collection.immutable.ListMap` preserves insertion order, you could also use a `LinkedHashMap` via the `Map` interface, which would then prevent access to any mutator methods.  This is easy enough to do by explicitly specifying the type:

```
val m: scala.collection.Map[Int,Int] = collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap(1->2, 2->3)
```

or (using type ascription):

```
val m = collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap(1->2, 2->3) : Map[Int,Int]
```

Comment: Unless the Map interface in your examples is a mutable.Map, that doesn't work. Hence my question regarding coverting that LinkedHashMap to an immutable map through the toMap method.

Comment: it's a `scala.collection.Map`, which is the common supertype of both `mutable.Map` and `immutable.Map`

Answer (score 8):

No, `LinkedHashMap.toMap` does not retain insertion order.

The best way I know is to convert it to a ListMap (immutable) :

```
def toMap[A, B](lhm: mutable.LinkedHashMap[A, B]): ListMap[A, B] = ListMap(lhm.toSeq: _*)
```

Simply hiding the mutation methods is not the same as converting to an immutable object.

Comment: +1 This actually answers the question in a different way than the more popular one. It shows how to convert a LHM to LM - which I found useful.

Comment: aren't listmaps preserved in backwards order? http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-choose-map-implementation-class-sorted-scala-cookbook

Comment: @AndrewNorman You can try it for yourself. `ListMap.apply` calls `++=` which does not invert the order

Comment: Interestingly, converting to mutable ListMap doesn't preserve order. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score -5):

You can use [TreeMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/TreeMap.html):

```
TreeMap(Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three").toArray:_*).map(println)
```

Comment: `TreeMap` is sorted by ordering, not by the order in which elements are added.