# Convert list to a map with key being an index in Scala

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, scala-collections

I have a list of strings

```
val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

and I want to have a map with keys as indexes of items in list. So I did the following:

```
def mapByIndexes(list: List[String]): Map[Int, String] = (1 to list.size).zip(list).toMap
```

However, the resulting map does not preserve the index order and I'm getting this as a result:

```
Map(5 -> "e", 1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d")
```

How can I modify the code above so I'm getting a map with the following, natural order?

```
Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d", 5 -> "e")
```

Note: I'm aware that I can just sort the resulting map, but can I avoid that step and create a map that already preserves the order?

Edit: Solution with `ListMap` described at [Scala LinkedHashMap.toMap preserves order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199186/scala-linkedhashmap-tomap-preserves-order) works, but I don't like additional parentheses and `_*` for so simple thing. Isn't there anything else so I can just have a chaining? If not, I will accept @pamu answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala LinkedHashMap.toMap preserves order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199186/scala-linkedhashmap-tomap-preserves-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm aware that I can just sort the resulting map

No, you can't. Sorting a `Map` doesn't make sense. But there are `Map` implementations which store keys in natural order, such as [`TreeMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap) ([`IntMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.IntMap) also does, IIRC). Note that it is *not* the same as preserving insertion order, as `ListMap` and `LinkedHashMap` do.

> Solution with ListMap described at Scala LinkedHashMap.toMap preserves order? works, but I don't like additional parentheses and _* for so simple thing. Isn't there anything else so I can just have a chaining?

No (at least, I don't think so), but you can easily define it:

```
implicit class ToListMap[A, B](x: Seq[(A, B)]) {
  def toListMap = ListMap(x: _*)
}

// somewhere where ToListMap is in scope or imported:
val list = List(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)
list.toListMap
```

Be aware that `ListMap` is basically a list (as the name says), so lookups in it are slower than any reasonable map implementation.

Of course, you can do exactly the same with `TreeMap`.

Comment: By sorting map I meant the things you described. If you google for "sort map scala" it shows exactly these :)

Comment: BTW, code you provided doesn't compile. I'm getting `type mismatch; found   : Seq[(A, B)] required: (?, ?)  def toListMap = ListMap(x)`

Comment: Hi Alexey - why didn't you mention `SortedMap`? Does it not address the OP's desire for a `map` sorted by its keys?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Because I already mention `TreeMap`, which is the implementation of `SortedMap`.

Comment: But I see `scala.collection.SortedMap` having 2 sub-classes: `scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap` and `scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap` - http://imgur.com/a/cETO0.

Comment: @KevinMeredith And if you go to `scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap` you'll see it's also a trait which has `scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap` as a subclass (though 2.12 also added `mutable` counterparts for both).

Comment: @MichalKordas Lost the `_*` somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ListMap`. After zipping instead of doing `toMap`, Just construct the `ListMap` which preserves the order of elements. You can build a ListMap using its companion object. It accepts var args of tuples.

```
def mapByIndexes(list: List[String]): ListMap[Int, String] = ListMap((1 to list.size).zip(list): _*)
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable._
import scala.collection.immutable._

scala> def mapByIndexes(list: List[String]): ListMap[Int, String] = ListMap((1 to list.size).zip(list): _*)
mapByIndexes: (list: List[String])scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,String]

scala> mapByIndexes(list)
res10: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> e)
```

Comment: Nice, works for me as well. I don't like additional parentheses and `_*` though. Isn't there anything else so I can just have a simple chaining?